# javafx.fxml.LoadException on switching from one window to other

Tags: java, javafx

I am using javaFXML. i am trying to open a option window on clicking on login button, but i am getting javafx.fxml.LoadException.I am giving entire code, please help me up.

**FXMLDocument.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="345.0" prefWidth="361.0" styleClass="mainFxmlClass" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="qwertyy.FXMLDocumentController">
<stylesheets>
    <URL value="@login.css" />
</stylesheets>
 <children>
  <AnchorPane layoutX="4.0" layoutY="-14.0" prefHeight="345.0" prefWidth="426.0">
     <children>
        <Label cache="true" cacheHint="QUALITY" depthTest="ENABLE" layoutX="66.0" layoutY="100.0" mnemonicParsing="true" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="111.0" text="Username">
           <font>
              <Font size="14.0" />
           </font></Label>
        <Label cache="true" cacheHint="QUALITY" depthTest="ENABLE" layoutX="67.0" layoutY="164.0" mnemonicParsing="true" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="73.0" text="Password">
           <font>
              <Font size="14.0" />
           </font></Label>
        <TextField id="usernm" fx:id="usernm" layoutX="140.0" layoutY="104.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="163.0" />
        <PasswordField fx:id="pwwd" layoutX="140.0" layoutY="168.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="163.0" />
        <Button layoutX="141.0" layoutY="231.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="73.0" text="Login" />
     </children>
  </AnchorPane>
 </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**FXMLDocumentController.java**

```
package qwertyy;

import java.awt.Dialog;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.fxml.JavaFXBuilderFactory;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;

import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {



 private Stage stage;

 private Qwertyy appln;


 public void setApp(Qwertyy qwer)
 {
 appln=qwer;
 }

@FXML
private TextField usernm,pwwd;

@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {

 URL u;

 URLConnection ucn;


 OutputStream os;


 byte[] sss;


 String msg;


 String usrnm,pwd,eusrnm,epwd,ousrnm;

    ousrnm=usernm.getText();
    usrnm=usernm.getText();
    pwd=pwwd.getText();


    msg="&usrnm="+usrnm+"&pwd="+pwd;


      sss=msg.getBytes();


              try{
        u=new URL("http://localhost:8088/profutil/CheckLogin");

        ucn=u.openConnection();
        ucn.setDoOutput(true);
        ucn.setDoInput(true);
        ucn.setRequestProperty("Content=length", String.valueOf(sss.length));
        os=ucn.getOutputStream();

        os.write(sss);
        os.flush();

        String inp;
            BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ucn.getInputStream()));

            inp=in.readLine();
                  System.out.println("input"+inp);
            while(inp!=null)
            {
                if(inp.equals("3"))
                {
                    System.out.println("in lab");
                    appln.swa();

                }
                if(inp.equals("1"))
                {

                }

                else
                {




                }



            inp=in.readLine();

            }


        os.close();
        }catch(Exception ee)
        {

   //         new Error(null, true, "Internet Connection Required");


            ee.printStackTrace();
        }



  }

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}
```

}

**Labopt.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="353.0" prefWidth="430.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="qwertyy.LaboptController">
<children>
  <ScrollPane layoutX="-1.0" layoutY="1.0" prefHeight="353.0" prefWidth="491.0">
     <content>
        <MenuBar prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="492.0">
          <menus>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="ViewAllOrders" />
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Preferences">
                 <items>
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Add" />
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit" />
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
                 </items>
            </Menu>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="ViewAllClients" />
              <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Messages">
                 <items>
                    <MenuItem fx:id="msg1" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#CompmsgAction" text="Compose" />
                    <MenuItem fx:id="msg2" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#InboxAction" text="Inbox" />
                    <MenuItem fx:id="msg3" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#SentAction" text="Sent" />
                 </items>
              </Menu>
              <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Notes">
                <items>
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Add Note" />
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="View Note" />
                </items>
              </Menu>
          </menus>
        </MenuBar>
     </content>
  </ScrollPane>
```

**LabOptController.java**

```
package qwertyy;

import java.awt.MenuItem;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
 import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
 import javafx.scene.Parent;
 import javafx.scene.Scene;
 import javafx.scene.control.Label;
 import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LaboptController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private MenuItem msg1,msg2,msg3;


   private Qwertyy application;


public void setApp(Qwertyy application){
    this.application = application;
}

@FXML
private void CompmsgAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {



}
@FXML
private void InboxAction(ActionEvent event) {


}
@FXML
private void SentAction(ActionEvent event) {


}
@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {

}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}    

}
```

**Qwertyy.java**

```
package qwertyy;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.fxml.JavaFXBuilderFactory;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


 public class Qwertyy extends Application {
 private Stage stage;
private final double MINIMUM_WINDOW_WIDTH = 390.0;
private final double MINIMUM_WINDOW_HEIGHT = 500.0;
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

   try {
        stage = primaryStage;
        stage.setTitle("FXML Login Sample");
        stage.setMinWidth(MINIMUM_WINDOW_WIDTH);
        stage.setMinHeight(MINIMUM_WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        gotoLogin();
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Qwertyy.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }  


}
 private void gotoLogin() {
    try {
        FXMLDocumentController login = (FXMLDocumentController) replaceSceneContent("FXMLDocument.fxml");
        login.setApp(this);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Qwertyy.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}



 public void swa()
 {
  gotoProfile();

}


 private void gotoProfile() {
    try {
        LaboptController profile = (LaboptController) replaceSceneContent("Labopt.fxml");
        profile.setApp(this);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Qwertyy.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
 }

private Initializable replaceSceneContent(String fxml) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    InputStream in = Qwertyy.class.getResourceAsStream(fxml);
    loader.setBuilderFactory(new JavaFXBuilderFactory());
    loader.setLocation(Qwertyy.class.getResource(fxml));
    AnchorPane page;
    try {
        page = (AnchorPane) loader.load(in);
    } finally {
        in.close();
    } 
    Scene scene = new Scene(page, 800, 600);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.sizeToScene();
    return (Initializable) loader.getController();
 }
}
```

**Exception generated**

```
Aug 12, 2014 5:05:27 PM qwertyy.Qwertyy gotoProfile
SEVERE: null
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
file:/C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Qwertyy/dist/run779804382/Qwertyy.jar!  /qwertyy/Labopt.fxml:26

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2595)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)
at qwertyy.Qwertyy.replaceSceneContent(Qwertyy.java:79)
at qwertyy.Qwertyy.gotoProfile(Qwertyy.java:65)
at qwertyy.Qwertyy.swa(Qwertyy.java:58)
at qwertyy.FXMLDocumentController.handleButtonAction(FXMLDocumentController.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1763)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1651)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(   at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8175)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at      com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3746)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3471)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1695)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2486)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:314)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:243)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:345)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:526)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:898)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.awt.MenuItem field     qwertyy.LaboptController.msg1 to javafx.scene.control.MenuItem
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:758)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processValue(FXMLLoader.java:857)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:745)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2723)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
... 62 more
```

Comment: It can't find your fxml file. Is it named correctly, and is the fxml file in the `qwertyy` package?

Comment: @James_D ya fxml file is named correctly and is in qwertyy package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, as clearly stated in the exception, is that the class `LaboptController` contains the fields `msg1`, `msg2`, `msg3` of type `java.awt.MenuItem`. It should be `javafx.scene.control.MenuItem`.

Just correct the imports.